# Radeon HD6570 only working in Linux Kernel 3.6.7

Tags: 64-bit, amd-radeon, linux-kernel, fedora-17

I have an interesting problem getting my Radeon HD6570 graphics card working in Fedora 17:
When booting into any Linux kernel version above 3.6.7-4, after GRUB finishes there is no video except for a flashing grey line across the top of the screen. However, when booting into kernel 3.6.7-4, (as I am now) everything is fine (with the exception of not being able to install the AMD drivers, as the kernel headers for 3.6.10 don't match what the installer was expecting).

Are there any known incompatabilities with the Radeon HD6570 and Linux kernel >3.6.7-4, or is there another problem?

Comment: Have you checked the bug website for the Fedora release?

Comment: Also you might want to check out the kernel change logs on www.kernel.org for this linux version.

Comment: @mdpc I am unable to find any incompatabilities or current bug reports to unsupported ATI/Radeon graphics cards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Kernel 6.11-5 fixed the problems.