# AMD driver installation kernel header issues

Tags: drivers, linux-kernel, fedora-17

I am having problems getting the AMD linux graphics drivers installed; every time I try to install it errors saying that it cannot find the kernel headers. The current kernel version running is 3.6.7-4, so the installer is looking for the 3.6.7-4 kernel headers. However, yum will only install the kernel headers for 3.6.10 and I am unable to find a package for the 3.6.7-4 headers.

What do I need to do to get the AMD drivers installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your problem correctly,
then type in the following command should resolve your issue(under rood).
yum install kernel-devel kernel-headers gcc gcc-c++

I am not too sure as to why it needs gcc-c++ but that worked for me.

I got the info from 
http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Fedora_17_Installation_Guide
but their site seems to be down.
So I feel like I should post this somewhere so the next time I reinstall my computer, I'll be able to find the answer.
Also, others can find the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

By saying `yum` you tipped me off to the fact that you *may* be running Fedora (or Oracle, or RHEL, or Scientific, or CentOS, or ...) so I'm going to assume you're running Fedora 17/18.

Since `yum` is trying to install the headers for `3.6.10`, that tells me you are running an outdated kernel. You need to `yum update` to the latest kernel, then reboot into that kernel, so that you are running the same kernel version as you have headers for. That's the only sane way to take care of this. Depending on how old your kernel is, the upgrade packages to your specific kernel version may not even be available still in the repos (although the original released packages of the distro may yet be available). Worst case, you may be able to find the kernel headers packages for your specific kernel verison on koji.fedoraproject.org

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this in my question... In my other (currently unanswered) question http://superuser.com/questions/521204/radeon-hd6570-only-working-in-linux-kernel-3-6-7 I posted about this setup and that my card is not working period in any kernel other than 3.6.7-4 (the others I have installed are 3.9 and 3.10). Also, I am running Fedora 17, I forgot to add the tag for it.

Comment: kernels 3.9 and 3.10 don't exist, so that doesn't make any sense... do you mean 3.6.9 and 3.6.10?

Comment: Also, if you really need to obtain the 3.6.7-4 headers, as I said, check http://koji.fedoraproject.org

Comment: Yep, sorry. I meant 3.6.9 and 3.6.10

Comment: also, either my Google-fu is not working or koji.fedoraproject.org doesn't have a package for the 3.6.7-4, only 3.6.7-2